# Office 365 newly purchased is not launching on my Big Sur Mac? What can I do?

Tags: macos, big-sur, office-365

I just installed big Sur on a Mac Book air. I purchased Office 365 and when I try to launch it, I gut just to base one, and then it stays stuck. What can I do?

Comment: There's a lot missing from here.  Did you do a clean install of Big Sur or just updated on top of what you had existing (I don't recommend the latter).  When did you purchase O365 and what installer are you using?  The name "Office 365" has been deprecated for "Microsoft 365" so you could be using an old installer.  What's "base one?"  Can you post a screen shot? Remember, we can't look over your shoulder!  Finally, did you try contacting Microsoft?  This is a paid product and you're entitled to support and assistance directly from the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

One easy thing is to use a browser (other than Safari) and go to https://portal.office.com and make sure your license is set up.

Depending on [which of the many versions of Office was sold to you](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/where-to-enter-your-office-product-key-0a82e5ae-739e-4b92-a6f4-2ec780c185db), you might want to start with Microsoft subscription support to know which level and version of the programs you purchased so you can activate and sign in correctly. The applications are all the same, but the license you bring to the app enables the features your account provides.

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/home/contact

Once the licensing is clear, then you can make sure you’re signing in to the apps and they pull the same license as your online check allows.

Comment: And note that once you are signed in and have verified your license MS has download links for the software you are licensed for. And depending on where you bought it the online version might be a more updated version.

Comment: I love downloading from https://macadmins.software, but the Office Portal is pretty good and simpler to navigate. @SteveChambers

Comment: Cool, I'm savin' *that* link!